# What might cause a network to fail to ping at first, then succeed

Tags: 14.04, networking, server

Every time I start up my server, no matter how long I leave it to "come online", the first few pings seem to fail to the machine (as does SSH, etc). Example:

```
josh@homeserv:/var/www/html/amp$ ping 192.168.0.200
PING 192.168.0.200 (192.168.0.200) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.0.201 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.201 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.201 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
64 bytes from 192.168.0.201: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=1195 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.201: icmp_seq=13 ttl=64 time=137 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.201: icmp_seq=15 ttl=64 time=128 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.201: icmp_seq=18 ttl=64 time=112 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.201: icmp_seq=19 ttl=64 time=2.89 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.201: icmp_seq=20 ttl=64 time=4.16 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.201: icmp_seq=21 ttl=64 time=5.55 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.201: icmp_seq=22 ttl=64 time=2.04 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.201: icmp_seq=23 ttl=64 time=2.64 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.201: icmp_seq=24 ttl=64 time=3.32 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.201: icmp_seq=25 ttl=64 time=4.13 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.201: icmp_seq=26 ttl=64 time=2.01 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.201: icmp_seq=27 ttl=64 time=3.07 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.201: icmp_seq=28 ttl=64 time=3.99 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.201: icmp_seq=29 ttl=64 time=5.05 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.201: icmp_seq=30 ttl=64 time=10.5 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.201: icmp_seq=31 ttl=64 time=2.93 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.201: icmp_seq=32 ttl=64 time=4.78 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.201: icmp_seq=33 ttl=64 time=9.18 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.201: icmp_seq=34 ttl=64 time=3.97 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.201: icmp_seq=35 ttl=64 time=2.06 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.201: icmp_seq=36 ttl=64 time=5.06 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.201: icmp_seq=37 ttl=64 time=3.00 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.201: icmp_seq=38 ttl=64 time=3.43 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.201: icmp_seq=39 ttl=64 time=3.64 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.201: icmp_seq=40 ttl=64 time=5.70 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.201: icmp_seq=41 ttl=64 time=2.57 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.201: icmp_seq=42 ttl=64 time=4.75 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.201: icmp_seq=43 ttl=64 time=2.32 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.201: icmp_seq=44 ttl=64 time=3.75 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.201: icmp_seq=45 ttl=64 time=33.5 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.201: icmp_seq=46 ttl=64 time=176 ms
```

Notice the first 3 fail, the 4th, 5th, and 6th are all slow, then we're normal until the last which goes super high. I can just about handle that "spike", but the startup is killing me given this is my "build" environment, it has to be stable and I have to reboot it regularly due to memory leaks and power requirements (RCD often goes, sometimes due to stuff I gotta do which takes longer than my backup power can last).

The connection is via wifi, so some degree of intermittent spiking is inevitable, however this seems 100% consistent, every time I boot the machine I have to tease the network interface into life before it will respond to me.

If log files are required, please advise which (I don't know what will be useful, have so far managed to avoid doing anything too heavy with networking and right now that avoidance is really making life more difficult.

Comment: How come you ping the .200 and get an answer from .201?

Comment: That's a damn fine question. I honestly don't have a clue. Didn't notice that before. Investigating now. Perhaps even more unusual, 192.168.0.200 is the machine from which the pings are being sent.